# Flutter Null Safety error while creating a Timer | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I getting this error while i shift my project from old version to new null safety version.
Here it show error ***The method '-' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').*** It shows error in the line `secondsRemaining--;` so i added a null check operator `secondsRemaining!--;` again it shows error as ***Illegal assignment to non-assignable expression.*** The below is my timer function.

```
int? secondsRemaining;
bool enableResend = false;
late Timer timer;

void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if (secondsRemaining != 0) {
          setState(() {
            secondsRemaining--;
          });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          enableResend = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113.  However, you should consider making `secondsRemaining` non-nullable.  It'd make more sense for `timer` to be nullable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null check on works if you re-write the code like this:

```
int? secondsRemaining;
bool enableResend = false;
late Timer timer;

void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if (secondsRemaining != 0 || secondsRemaining != null) {
          setState(() {
            secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining! - 1;
          });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          enableResend = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```